# Printing top 10 recurring words in a file

Tags: c, file, io, segmentation-fault

Edited question:
Hi guys, my goal is to print the top 10 occurring words in a file, I have managed to get everything to work from reading the file to counting word occurrences and printing it, but when I implement my qsort I get a segfault. I looked over my pointers and they look okay to me, I would appreciate any feedback.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 51

struct words
{
  char *ch;
  int index;
  struct words *pNext;
};



struct words* createWordCounter(char *ch)
{
  struct words *pCounter = NULL;
  pCounter = (struct words*)malloc(sizeof(char));
  pCounter->ch = (char*)malloc(strlen(ch)+1);
  strcpy(pCounter->ch, ch);
  pCounter->index = 1;
  pCounter->pNext = NULL;
  return pCounter;
}

struct words *pStart = NULL;

char* removePunc(struct words* ch)
{
  char *src = ch, *dst = ch;

  while (*src)
  {
     if (ispunct((unsigned char)*src))
     {

        src++;
     }
     else if (isupper((unsigned char)*src))
     {

        *dst++ = tolower((unsigned char)*src);
        src++;
     }
     else if (src == dst)
     {

        src++;
        dst++;
     }
     else
     {

        *dst++ = *src++;
     }
  }

  *dst = 0;
}

void addWord(char *word)
{
  struct words *pCounter = NULL;
  struct words *pLast = NULL;

  if(pStart == NULL)
  {
    pStart = createWordCounter(word);
    return;
  }


  pCounter = pStart;
  while(pCounter != NULL)
  {
    if(strcmp(word, pCounter->ch) == 0)
    {
      ++pCounter->index;
      return;
    }
    pLast = pCounter;
    pCounter = pCounter->pNext;
  }
  pLast->pNext = createWordCounter(word);
}

void printWord(struct words *pCounter)
{


  printf("\n%-30s  %5d\n", pCounter->ch, pCounter->index);

}
//sort
int compare (const void * a, const void * b){
  struct words *A1 = (struct words *)a;
  struct words *B1 = (struct words *)b;
  return B1->index - A1->index;
/*
  if ((A1->count - B1->count) > 0)
        return -1;
  else if ((A1->count - B2->count) < 0)
        return 1;
  else
        return 0;
*/
}



int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  struct words *pCounter = NULL;


  char temp[MAX];
  FILE *fpt;


  if(argc == 2)
  {

    printf("File name is: %s\n",argv[1]);
    fpt = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    //fail test
    if(fpt == NULL)
    {
      printf("cannot open file, exiting program...\n");
      exit(0);
    }

    //get the data out of the file and insert in struct
    int wordCounter = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int lines = 0;
    while((fscanf(fpt, "%s ", &temp)) == 1)
    {

        removePunc(temp);
        addWord(temp);

        if(temp == ' ')
          i++;
        if(temp == '\n')
          lines++;

        wordCounter++;
    }


/*
    pCounter = pStart;
    while(pCounter != NULL)
    {
      printWord(pCounter);
      pCounter = pCounter->pNext;
    }
*/
  //sort
    qsort(pCounter, wordCounter, sizeof(struct words), compare);
    for(int j = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       printWord(pCounter);
    }

  }

  fclose(fpt);
  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is the size of temp array when you try to using fscanf.

```
while((fscanf(fpt, "%s ", temp)) == 1)
```

When the length of one line is bigger than MAX, segmentation fault occur.

You can change your code like this

```
#define SCANF_LEN2(x) #x
#define SCANF_LEN(x) SCANF_LEN2(x)

//...
//your original code
//...

while((fscanf(fpt, "%"SCANF_LEN(MAX)"s ", temp)) == 1)
```

By the way, you should check

(1) compile warning about type

`char* removePunc(struct words* ch)`
should be `char* removePunc(char *ch)`

`if(temp == ' ')` should be `if(temp[0] == ' ')`

`if(temp == '\n')` should be `if(temp[0] == '\n')`

(2) malloc size

`pCounter = (struct words*)malloc(sizeof(char));` should be `pCounter = (struct words*)malloc(sizeof(struct words));`

(3) remember free after using malloc

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback, however, I made significant changes to my program from the time I uploaded it, and now I'm not sure where but I'm making a mistake with my compare function that I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 1):

First `temp` is already a pointer, so do not include `'&'` before it in `fscanf`. Second, don't skimp on buffer size (e.g. `#define MAX 1024`). Third, protect your array bounds with the *field-width* modifier and don't put trailing whitespace in your *format-string*.

Putting it altogether (presuming you use `1024 as MAX`, you can use

```
fscanf(fpt, "1023%s", temp))
```

Well done on checking the return of `fscanf` during your read.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out and answering my question, however, I managed to fix those issues but when I wrote a new sort function and tried to implement it I get a segfault, would you happen to know what could cause that?

Comment: @mahdi - `qsort(pCounter, wordCounter, sizeof(struct words), compare);` where is `pCounter` assigned? Where is `compare` defined?

Comment: `compare` would be better as `return (A1->index > B1->index) - (A1->index < B1->index);` to avoid potential *overflow*.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the things that have already been mentioned.

In `createWordCounter(...)`

```
pCounter = (struct words*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

you are allocating memory for a `char`. Even though the pointer to a struct is the pointer to its first member, the first element of `words` is a pointer to a char. It is better to be careful and write

```
struct words *pCounter = malloc(sizeof *pCounter);
```

Also, be mindful of operator precedence.
In `addWord(...)` you have

```
++pCounter->index;
```

What that does is increment the pointer `pCounter` before accessing `index`. If you are trying to increment `index`, it should be

```
++(pCounter->index);
```

or

```
pCounter->index++;
```

I recommend striping your program down to its bare essentials and test each part one at a time systematically to narrow down the cause of your errors.